# Why is jsonObjects[i].type undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

When I click (`onclick="changeTyp"`) its supossed to change the value to my clicked Interval. But It says Undefined on `jsonObjects[i].type`.
Maybe I have to send `jsonObjects[i]` to `changeType` function?
Can somebody give me a hint on what I should do?

**I declared jsonObjects:**

```
var jsonObjects = []; 

function populateTypes() {

    for(i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {

        if(availableTypes.indexOf(jsonObjects[i].type) < 0) {

            availableTypes.push(jsonObjects[i].type);
            $("#changetotypes").append('<li><a href="#" onclick="changeType(\'' + jsonObjects[i].type + '\')">' + jsonObjects[i].type + '</a></li>');
       } 
    }
}

function changeType(type) {

    $( "#currenttype" ).html("Aktuell Typ: " + jsonObjects[i].type);
}
```

**This is my HTML code:**

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><span id="currenttype" title=""></span></a>
    <ul id="changetotypes"></ul>
</li>
```

**That's the jsonObjects file:**

```
"c3000": {"x": 675, "y": 269, "plan":1, "name":"c3000", "img":"sensor3.png", "added":"datetime", "type":"c", "interval":"0", "comment":"enmassatext", "active":true, "value":"4c", "radie":false, "alarm":false},
"r3002": {"x": 223, "y": 355, "plan":1, "name":"r3002", "img":"sensor2.png", "added":"datetime", "type":"r", "interval":"6", "comment":"enmassatext", "active":true, "value":"-4c", "radie":false, "alarm":true},
"r3003": {"x": 300, "y": 100, "plan":1, "name":"r3003", "img":"sensor1.png", "added":"datetime", "type":"e", "interval":"3", "comment":"enmassatext", "active":false, "value":"15c", "radie":false, "alarm":false},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your trying to loop over an array structure that doesn't exist. Your JSON defines an object that contains a set of objects, not an array of objects. So instead of:

```
var jsonObject = [obj, obj, obj];
```

the JS structure you end up with is:

```
var jsonObject = { c3000: obj, r3002: obj, r3002: obj};
```

(I'm not sure why you're declaring `jsonObjects` at the top as an array.)

The loop you should therefore be using is:

```
// var your loop variables or you'll end up in trouble
for (var k in jsonObjects) {
  var type = jsonObjects[k].type;
  if (availableTypes.indexOf(type) < 0) {
    availableTypes.push(type);
    $('#changetotypes').append('<li><a class="typechange" data-type="' + type + '">' + type + '</a></li>');
  }
}
```

And since you're using jQuery, remove the inline JS and use a class and data attribute instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.typechange', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(this).data('type');
  $('#currenttype').html('Aktuell Typ: ' + type);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ab7f/2/)

Comment: Ok, Its working with your code. But how do I save the new clicked type(Interval)? I wanna be able to save the new clicked/choosen type(interval)?

Comment: I don't understand. Your question doesn't mention anything like that.

Comment: Save the type where? And what's `interval`?

Comment: Sorry Andy, I mean save the new type value to my jsonObject file. Interval is "type".

Comment: That's a whole other question. If you can't figure it out, post another question to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/4zXkJ/

Your JSON is an object, not an array, here's how you can loop through object's properties:

```
for(var i in jsonObjects) {

    if(availableTypes.indexOf(jsonObjects[i].type) < 0) {

        availableTypes.push(jsonObjects[i].type);
        $("#changetotypes").append('<li><a href="#" onclick="changeType(\'' + jsonObjects[i].type + '\')">' + jsonObjects[i].type + '</a></li>');
   } 
}
```

Also in `changeType` use the type parameter:

```
function changeType(type) {
    $( "#currenttype" ).html("Aktuell Typ: " + type);
}
```